# Why do I get logged out of my Google Account when I log out of a web-app?

Tags: google-account, login

I log on to a web-app using my Google Account—Khan Academy for example. When I logout of Khan Academy I also get logged out of my Google Account (surely this is a major flaw in user experience).

What is the reason for this behaviour?

Comment: What's the reason for signing out of your account?

Answer (score 2):

Most Google Account based apps become nearly one and the same thing once you connect them with your Google Account, and logging out of there logs you out of Google Account as well. They just kind of expect you not to log out, like most people stay logged in Gmail even after they've read their morning emails.
Edit: And I agree, it really is a major flaw in user experience